# Curl post json 415

Tags: post, json, curl

В общем, ситуация такая: получаю на своем сервере от приложения Content-Type: application/json

С этим все ок.

Но далее мне весь этот контент надо передать БЕЗ изменений на другой сервер, делаю это так:

```
$value = file_get_contents('php://input');

$ch = curl_init();

$curlConfig = array(
    CURLOPT_URL => 'http://сервер/',
    CURLOPT_POST => true,
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => FALSE,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $value
   );

    curl_setopt_array($ch, $curlConfig);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    "Accept: text/xml, application/xml, application/xhtml+xml, text/html;q=0.9, text/plain;q=0.8, text/css, image/png, image/jpeg, image/gif;q=0.8, application/x-shockwave-flash, video/mp4;q=0.9, flv-application/octet-stream;q=0.8, video/x-flv;q=0.7, audio/mp4, application/futuresplash, */*;q=0.5,
    Content-Type: application/json"
   ));
   $result = curl_exec($ch); 
   echo $result;
```

В ответ получаю 415 ошибку.
Причем если на этот сервер напрямую сделать запрос, скажем, с fiddlera

```
  POST http://Сервер/ HTTP/1.1
  Content-Type: application/json
  Host: Сервер
  {"account_id":211302694}
```

то запрос проходит на ура.
Где я допустил ошибку?
По сути, я же ничего не менял, просто отправил запрос дальше.

Comment: Какой content-type ответа? В ваше хэдере `Accept:` не указан например, `json`, и если ответ конечного сервера в json, он просто не может его отправить вашему cURL'у, т.к. тот заявил, что не умеет его принимать.

Просто уберите весь хэдер `Accept`.

Answer (score 2):

```
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $value
```

$value - должен быть ассоциативным массивом, где ключём является переменная пост, у Вас же просто строка без значения переменной, какой Вы эту строку присваиваете.

Comment: Неверно. Можно так передать и любые данные, в т.ч. строку или тело бинарного файла.